# How to get each element (parent child subchilds) name and their attributes -PHP -XML

Tags: php, xml

CHECK MY CODE HERE WHAT TO DO NEXT :

http://3v4l.org/KAYVr

RELEVANT CODE:

```
<?php
$file = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
   <product description="Cardigan Sweater" id="123" value="" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="Red"/>
             <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="burgundy"/>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
           <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="Red"/>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg" id="color" value="burgundy"/>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
   </product>
</catalog>
XML;
echo ("<pre>");

  $xml=simplexml_load_string($file) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

//ROOT:

foreach($xml as $root=>$value) {

          echo $root. '<br/>' ;


//check child 

          foreach ($value as $secondtag=>$value1) {
                 print_r($secondtag);echo "<br/>";
                if($value1->children() != null) {
                $subchild = $value1->children();
print_r($subchild);
               }
}

echo ("</pre>");


}
?>
```

I want to print it like
print root element 
    print (all root attribute if any)
print child element (if any)
    print (all child attributes if any)
print sub child (if any)
    print (all sub child attributes if any)

this should be recursive for every root element of file and it should every element's child and their attributes whole xml is printed systematically

expected output

```
catalog
   product 
 description="Cardigan Sweater" 
 id="123"
 value="" 
product_image="cardigan.jpg"
  catalog_item
   gender="Men's"
     size 
    description="Medium"
    color_swatch
 image="red_cardigan.jpg" 
id="color"
 value="Red"
  color_swatch 
image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg" 
id="color" 
value="burgundy"
   size
 description="Large"
  color_swatch 
image="red_cardigan.jpg"
 id="color" 
value="Red"
            color_swatch
 image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg"
 id="color"
 value="burgundy"
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: http://3v4l.org/KAYVr this is the relevant code

Comment: you could use `SimpleXMLIterator` and `recursiveIteratorIterator` if you just want to plainly output nodes

Comment: that will also output the attributes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$file` being your XML string:

```
$sxi = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new SimpleXMLIterator($file),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

// print root element
echo $sxi->getName(), PHP_EOL;

foreach ($sxi as $node) {
    // print element names
    echo str_repeat("\t", $sxi->getDepth() +1),
    $node->getName(),
    PHP_EOL;
    // print attributes
    foreach ($node->attributes() as $name => $value) {
        echo str_repeat("\t", $sxi->getDepth() +2),
        "$name: $value",
        PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

will output:

```
catalog
    product
        description: Cardigan Sweater
        id: 123
        value: 
        product_image: cardigan.jpg
        catalog_item
            gender: Men's
            size
                description: Medium
                color_swatch
                    image: red_cardigan.jpg
                    id: color
                    value: Red
                color_swatch
                    image: burgundy_cardigan.jpg
                    id: color
                    value: burgundy
            size
                description: Large
                color_swatch
                    image: red_cardigan.jpg
                    id: color
                    value: Red
                color_swatch
                    image: burgundy_cardigan.jpg
                    id: color
                    value: burgundy
```